# How to open a port for all users: NSA 2400

Tags: firewall, port

I'm trying to open up port 8332 for all users behind my firewall but can only find instructions for doing so for a single IP address.  How do I make sure all my users can use a specific port?

I've got a Sonicwall NSA 2400.

Edit: This is not to expose a server, but to add this port to the allowed list of ports.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you only allow users to get out on approved ports (web, mail, etc) and would like to add this to your approved list? Or do you have a server behind the 2400 that you would like to make public on port 8332 to users not on your LAN?

Comment: No server. I would just like this port to become part of the approved list.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a firewall rule like the existing rules you have for you approved list. A generic allow rule would look like this:

```
From: LAN
To: WAN
Service: 8332 (You'll create this in Service Objects)
Source: Firewalled Subnets
Destination: Any
Users: All
Schedule: Always On
```

Alternatively if you have an approved list as you say presumably that is a service group so you could create the new service object for 8332 and add it to the group.

Comment: [Found this on Dell Support](https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw4535) - States it covers SonicOS Enhanced (I'm not sure if that is the case here.)